# Syntax error in Conda

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am in Ipython notebook. I have anaconda version 1.9.1. I am simply trying to update my packages using conda but am getting a really simple error. Let me know if any other info would be helpful. Thanks much in advance.

```
IN
import conda
conda.__version__

OUT
'3.1.1'

IN
conda update conda

ERROR
  File "<ipython-input-34-b1c2cd000ad9>", line 1
    conda update conda
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda` is run from the shell, not a Python REPL.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to running stuff out of the shell. when i ran the shell out of the anaconda file it worked.